Google Play `purchases.subscriptionsv2.revoke` API - "Field revocation_context is missing"
The documentation for the purchases.subscriptionsv2.revoke method indicates that it has a required revocationContext field object, within which is a single, optional, proratedRefund field object.
Based on this documentation, I am lead to believe that I can revoke a subscription without granting a prorated refund by passing the following body:
{
  "revocationContext": {}
}

However, I am getting the following error:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Field revocation_context must have a refund type set.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Field revocation_context must have a refund type set.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}

Here are all the other variations of body that I have tried...

{}

{
  "revocationContext": null
}

{
  "revocationContext": {
    "proratedRefund": null
  }
}

... all failing.
Is it possible to revoke a subscription without granting a prorated refund? If so, what am I doing wrong?
